# Firefox CSS3 animations not working at all

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

So I'm stuck on what I've done wrong with my animation code.  I have

```
-webkit-animation: wave 200s linear 0s infinite;
-moz-animation: wave 200s linear 0s infinite;
animation: wave 200s linear 0s infinite;
```

and

```
    @keyframes wave {
    0% {
    background-position-x: 0%;
    }
    100% {
    background-position-x: 100%;
    }

    }

    @-moz-keyframes wave {
    0% {
    background-position-x: 0%;
    }
    100% {
    background-position-x: 100%;
    }

    }

    @-webkit-keyframes wave {
    0% {
        top: 20px;
    background-position-x: 0%;
 }
100% {
    top: 60px;
   background-position-x: 100%;
}

}
```

Now Chrome and Safari work just fine.  As soon as I fire up firefox, this animation doesn't play at all.  Is there a possibility I have just overlooked something here?  I've been trying different methods all day and nothing seems to work.  Any help is really appreciated!  Thank you!

**EDIT**: Heres the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WMh/).  As you can see, it works on chrome but not on FF.

Comment: Any chance you can throw together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: give me a few minutes.

Comment: I put the jsfiddle up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an illegal property, `background-position-x` instead of using the [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) property and *only* specifying the horizontal offset and 0 for the vertical offset. Changing this will fix it:

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WMh/3/)

```
@keyframes wave {

    0% {
    background-position: 0% 0;
    }

    100% {
    background-position: 100% 0; /* Obviously do the same for the prefixes */
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm.  While this seemed to work on the jsfiddle in my firefox, my actual site still doesn't work... such a pain.  Should I just resort to using jquery animations for this one?

Comment: Nope - it should work fine - if you post *all* relevant code I don't mind taking a look :)

Comment: well heres the new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T3WMh/4/) with the parent code of what i'm working with.  The code is in the `li` to be used with a parallax plugin.

Comment: It works fine for me on FF 15.0.01 - also you didn't change the `-webkit` properties from `background-position-x` to `background-position`

Comment: Yeah the jsfiddle works fine for me too.  In either case the animation isn't that big of a deal and if I can't figure it out, I'll drop it.  Thank you for the help though, I'll mark your comment as the answer because it was, I just have a different set of problems now :P

Answer (score 1):

Oooh I know the answer to this!  I actually ran into this problem a few weeks back, so there's nothing wrong with the animation but the background-position-x style.  I guess it's not actually a real style (although several browsers let you use it).  Firefox doesn't support it at all.  So you'll have to do background-position: x y   which is annoying to always have to put the y in there when you only want to change the X.